# How to set a max width to VideoView captions in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I currently have the following for the video view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myVideoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/my_video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="49dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:background="@drawable/exit_button_outline"
            android:src="@mipmap/btn_rdv_close"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/home_btn_desc"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closed_captions"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/closed_caption_button"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_off"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/home"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:nextFocusRight="@id/home"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/video_view"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/video_view"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/video_view"
            android:contentDescription="@string/closed_caption_button_content_description" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And in the code, I have the following:

```
videoView.addSubtitleSource(
    getClosedCaptionsFromFile(closedCaptionsFileName),
    MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/vtt", deviceLang)
)


videoView.setOnInfoListener { mp, what, extra ->
            var tracksInfo: Array<TrackInfo> = mp.trackInfo

            for ((index, track) in tracksInfo.withIndex()) {
                if (track.trackType == MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_SUBTITLE) {
                    if (closedCaptions) {
                        mp.selectTrack(index)
                    } else {
                        mp.deselectTrack(index)
                    }
                }
            }
            true
        }
```

We use a VTT file for captions. The problem is if the text in VTT file is long, then the text overlaps with the "closed_captions" button.

Is there a way to set max width of the closed captions so that it doesn't overlap with the subtitles button? If the captions exceed the max width, they should go to new line.

Image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't appear to have a built-in way to limit width.
However, since I'm using VTT file, it is possible to do it through VTT syntax by changing the `size` parameter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API